# TypeToken Object is not displayed correctly in the server

Tags: java, android, gson, typetoken

I'm new to TypeTokens and I'm having a problem. I have a shopping cart with products, and
those products I save to Shared Preferences using Typetoken. Because I need to delete and
remove products from recyclerview. Here what I have for adding products:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
            ArrayList<Artikujt> artikullObject = gson
                    .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());
            if (artikullObject != null) {
                artikullObject.add(mArtikull);
                String jsonString = gson.toJson(artikullObject);
                mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", jsonString);
                mEditor.apply();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Artikujt> arrayArtikuj = new ArrayList<>();
                arrayArtikuj.add(mArtikull);
                Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>() {}.getType();
                String s = gson.toJson(arrayArtikuj, listOfTestObject);
                mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", s);
                mEditor.apply();
            }
```

Now I need to send this object to server with some additional information, as below:

```
private void sendBasketItemsToServer() {
        //service where retrofit instance is defined for current route
        ProductsService prodService = new ProductsService();

        // Retrieve the product of the shopping cart which are saved in shred preferences
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor my_editor = preferences.edit();
        String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Artikujt> artikujt = gson
                .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());
        final int order_number = new Random().nextInt(26) + 75;
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        // initialize requestBody
        RequestBody requestBody = null;

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            jsonObject.put("klienti", full_name);
            jsonObject.put("adresa", fullAddress);
            jsonObject.put("produktet", artikujt);
            jsonObject.put("date", date);
            jsonObject.put("order_number", String.valueOf(order_number));
            requestBody = RequestBody.create(String.valueOf(jsonObject),
                    MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));

            System.out.println(jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get token, stored in shared preferences
        SharedPreferences editor = Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext())
                .getSharedPreferences(TOKEN_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = editor.getString("token", "");
        Callback<BasketResponse> callback = new Callback<BasketResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<BasketResponse> call, Response<BasketResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    // clear products added to cart
                    my_editor.clear();
                    my_editor.apply();

                    System.out.println(response.body());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CheckoutActivity.this, SuccessOrderActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<BasketResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        prodService.sendBasketItemsToServer(callback, token, requestBody);
    }
```

All of the items are sent to server and I'm receiving a code 200 as response, but I have a
problem with products, with this line:

```
jsonObject.put("produktet", artikujt);
```

is displayed like this:
[image]

Is sending the name of the class, not products. When I debug in Android Studio, everything
seems okay

[image]

I have two days figuring out how to solve this, but I don't know how. Can someone have any
suggestion what I'm missing here or what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I want to send to server a json like below:

```
{
    "klienti": "my name",
    "address": "my address",
    "products": [
        {
             "id": 1,
             "price": 2234,
             "category": 3,
             "created_at": 23-03-2020
        },
        {
             "id": 2,
             "price": 2534,
             "category": 3,
             "created_at": 23-03-2020
        }
    ],
    "date": 03-09-2020,
    "order_number": 93
}
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with expected and actual json in text format?

Answer (score 1):

`jsonObject.put("produktet", artikujt);`

This line is simply adding the java object to `jsonObject`.
You can instead do

`jsonObject.put("produktet", new Gson().toJson(artikujt));`

**Edit:**
If you are using `org.json.JSONObject`, try

```java
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
artikujt.forEach(item -> {
    jsonArray.put(new JSONObject(item));
});
jsonObject.put("produktet", jsonArray);
```

---

Though better solution would be to create a java class denoting your target json.

```java
class ArtikujtData {
    private String klienti;
    private String address;
    private List<Artikujt> products;
    private String date;
    @SerializedName(value = "order_number")
    private String orderNumber;

   // setters and getters
}
```

Create object of `ArtikujtData` and set values to it and use it as

`requestBody = RequestBody.create(new Gson().toJson(artikujtData),MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));`

Comment: jsonObject.put("produktet", new Gson().toJson(artikujt)), is not working

Comment: Is sending all products as one string/

Comment: What is complete package name of `JSONObject ` class? Can you try using the alternate solution of creating a separate class and setting data to it.

Comment: I have to change a lot of things, if I want to try another solution.

Comment: What is complete package name of JSONObject class?

Comment: I tried and I'm receiving an error: java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

Comment: jsonArray.put(new JSONObject(item));

Comment: Interesting, `artikujt` is of type `ArrayList<Artikujt>`. So, `item` would be of type `Artikujt` and not `String`.